# php and mysql, how to fond out someones place in a database

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table like this:

```
id    money
210   1000
321   1300
121   980
```

i want to know on witch place is `321` or any other id, so, in my case, i should have `321 is on 1'st place`

not sure if i can do this only with mysql..

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Do you mean to order the result by `money`?

Comment: sure, but more precisely on what place from that table an id is

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT q.id, 
       q.money, 
       @curRow := @curRow +1, 
       CONCAT( q.id, ' is on ', @curRow , ' place ' ) AS a
FROM (
SELECT 210 AS id, 1000 AS money
UNION
SELECT 321 AS id, 1300 AS money
UNION
SELECT 121 AS id, 980 AS money
)q
JOIN (

SELECT @curRow :=0
)r
ORDER BY q.money DESC
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT q.id, 
       q.money, @curRow := @curRow +1, 
       CONCAT( q.id, ' is on ', @curRow , ' place ' ) AS a
FROM (

SELECT 210 AS id, 1000 AS money
UNION
SELECT 321 AS id, 1300 AS money
UNION
SELECT 121 AS id, 980 AS money
)q
JOIN (

SELECT @curRow :=0
)r
ORDER BY q.money DESC
)q1
WHERE q1.id =210
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't really work, because i only know one id (any one)

Comment: please look at update of my answer

Comment: why do i have to pass `SELECT 210 AS id, 1000 AS money UNION SELECT 321 AS id, 1300 AS money...`? i don't know them i only know `q1.id =210`

Comment: this is table data which you provide in question. as i understood you have a `table` with 2 fields ( `id` and `name` ) and `select` with `union` simulate table data istead selects put your `table` and `id` in `where` condition comes from script.

Answer (score 3):

```
SET @rank=0;

SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, id, money
FROM table
ORDER BY money DESC
```